# Running apps from sdk on nexus 4

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, nexus-4

I wanted to play around with Ubuntu Touch, so I installed the Ubuntu SDK 2.8.1 and dual-booted my Nexus 4 with Ubuntu and Android. But when I connect my Nexus to the SDK, I can start an ssh session (with Ctrl + F10), but I cannot run an app on my device (using Ctrl + F12). I get the following error message:

`bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Invalid argument.`
  `bash: no job control in this shell`

I also get about ten messages everytime I want to run, saying:

`warning: permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:2222' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.`

I am totally new to all this phone SDK stuff, so if I haven't given enough info, please let me know.

Comment: Are you running it from QtCreator with ctrl+f12?

Comment: Yes I do, and then it runs /usr/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/scripts/qtc_device_run_app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I installed the qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-common package, it worked